# Error adjusting for cell counts using methylclock::DNAmAge()

Tags: r

I have encountered an error while attempting to use `DNAmAge()` to obtain DNAmAge, AgeAcDiff, IEAA, and EEAA from a methylation dataset.

I'm running the code below:

```
DNAmAge(Beta,
                         clocks=c("Horvath"),
                         toBetas=FALSE,
                         cell.count=TRUE,
                         cell.count.reference = "blood gse167998",
                         age=60,
                         min.perc=0.25)
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error in DNAmAge(Beta, clocks = c("Horvath"), toBetas = FALSE, cell.count = TRUE,  : 
  cell counts cannot be estimated since
                meffilEstimateCellCountsFromBetas function is giving an error.
                Probably your data do not have any of the required CpGs for that
                reference panel.
In addition: Warning message:
In knnimp(x, k, maxmiss = rowmax, maxp = maxp) :
  40589 rows with more than 50 % entries missing;
 mean imputation used for these rows
```

The error appears to indicate that I do not have the appropriate CpGs for "blood gse167998."

However, I know that my beta matrix contains the CpGs in Salas et al. 2022 because I used the `FlowSorted.BloodExtended.EPIC` comparison table and dataset to perform leukocyte deconvolution on my own dataset.

This also happens when I try to use other reference sets, e.g., Salas' "blood idoloptimized epic."

I took a look at the `meffilEstimateCellCountsFromBetas` function within `DNAmAge()` using `trace("DNAmAge", edit=T)`. I thought maybe this error was thrown because `meffilEstimateCellCountsFromBetas()` is now `meffil.estimate.cell.counts.from.betas()`.

I updated the name of the `meffil` function in `DNAmAge()`. Unfortunately, the same error occurred.

I posted the issue to the `methylclock` GitHub, but it looks like the issues aren't frequently checked.

Is anyone able to assist me in figuring out why this is happening?

Also, do you know if I am somehow able provide my own cell type estimates?

Thank you very much!